# Creating Compound Controls With Custom XML Attributes

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm been trying to combine a TextView and an EditText into one compound control which uses custom xml elements to pass in default values for each individual element. I've been looking at the tutorials/docs here:
[Building Compound Controls](http://m.androidside.com/docs/docs1.5/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound)
[Passing Custom Attributes](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/05/02/android-tutorial-42-passing-custom-variables-via-xml-resource-files/)

What I have so far.

Attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="FreeText">
        <attr name="label" format="string" />
        <attr name="default" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

My Main Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <com.example.misc.FreeText  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        myapp:label="label"
        myapp:default="default"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Compound Control, FreeText:

```
public class FreeText extends LinearLayout {

    TextView label;
    EditText value;

    public FreeText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.weight = 1;

        label = new TextView(context);
        addView(label, lp);

        value = new EditText(context);
        addView(value, lp);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FreeText);
        CharSequence s = a.getString(R.styleable.FreeText_label);
        if (s != null) { 
            label.setText(s);
        }

        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

When I run the program I see the views OK but the value of my CharSequence, s, is always null.  Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I hate it when you notice the problem right after you ask for help.

The problem was that my namespace for my custom XML elements should have been like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <com.example.misc.FreeText  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        myapp:label="label"
        myapp:default="default"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And I love the fact that you noticed the problem right after asking for help, and not before! You've saved me a lot of digging for the same answer elsewhere. Thanks!